# Projection Queries vs. Regular Queries

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, projection

Reading the documentation on Cloud Datastore, it's pretty clear that a Get retrieves the entire entity, and that a query is always done against the index.

Here's where it gets confusing, because according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries):

> Projection queries allow you to query Cloud Datastore for just those
>   specific properties of an entity that you actually need, at lower
>   latency and cost than retrieving the entire entity

But if all queries are done against an index, a query would never retrieve the entire entity anyway as everything is taken from the index? If I have an index with 3 properties (A, B and C) there shouldn't be any difference in using a regular query or a projection query, because I can't "project" just A and B, as the index also contains C, so in this example I would have to "project" the same properties as the regular query?

It seems to me that projection queries can only really be used when an index doesn't contain all the properties on an entity? So if an entity doesn't have a lot of properties, it doesn't make any sense to use projection because most (if not all) queries will be using/getting all the properties anyway? I'm wondering if makes sense cost-wise to use projection in this case, because the documentation says that projection has `lower latency and cost` but would that apply to projection when grabbing all properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries#Python_Indexes_for_projections) (probably the same article you're looking at), `Projection queries require all properties specified in the projection to be included in a Cloud Datastore index`.

Whereas "regular" (which I'm taking to mean `SELECT * ...`) queries against Cloud Datastore typically use indexes that only contain a sorted subset of the properties of the queried entities, plus pointers to the full entities, projection queries run against indexes that contain all the fields requested by the query. So it appears the significant latency gain comes from the elimination of the need to fetch the queried entities once the set of entities matching the query has been discerned via the index.

So when you write `if all queries are done against an index, a query would never retrieve the entire entity anyway as everything is taken from the index?`, that's not accurate: Non-projection queries are going to:

1. Determine the index needed to efficiently fulfill the query (if the index doesn't exist, an exception will be raised)
2. Use it to get pointers to the matching entities, and
3. Fetch those matching entities

As far as I can tell, projection queries are the only mechanism Cloud Datastore provides for fulfilling a query using only an index (without step #3 above).

I haven't read any documentation suggesting that, even if you do configure an index containing all the properties across all entities of a particular datastore kind (which would be unusual), the query engine would be "smart" enough to use that index to fulfill queries without step #3 above even where *technically* possible. Indeed, since Cloud Datastore is schemaless and entities of the same kind can have different properties, even knowing whether or not an index contains all the properties for a given entity without fetching that entity would be a much more involved task than it would be with a database with schema.

Comment: That is really interesting, so the only way to guarantee that a query is done using just the index is by using projection? Which would also mean that any query that isn't done using projection will actually end up also fetching the underlying entities, which obviously carry a much higher cost?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes, projection queries are the only way to use just the index when running a query. I can't speak to the magnitude of the latency differences, but projection queries are an optimization that I've often chosen to skip for simplicity, though a "best practice" they may be (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#queries). Of course, more indexes mean more stored data which has a cost (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing#storage_size_consideration). Interestingly though, running projection queries are cheaper ($-wise) according to that article.

Comment: I don't think the index contains entity properties, see my answer.

Comment: @DanCornilescu, per the documentation, `Projection queries require all properties specified in the projection to be included in a Cloud Datastore index`, so indexes definitely contain (the indexed) properties. More documentation of this is [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_definition_and_structure): `An index table contains a column for every property named in the index's definition.` The sorted properties in the index are what allow queries to determine which entities to fetch or, in the case of projection queries, bypass the fetching of the entire entity.

Comment: @jgaul you may be right. I'll delete my answer. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @DanCornilescu no worries--I learned a lot investigating the nuances of this too!

Comment: @KieranW. Keys only queries will also only use an index to return the results.  A keys_only query is a specific form of projection query.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the great feedback. I couldn't "decipher" this from the documentation.