# Type mismatch with projection on a []byte property

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a struct as follows

```
  type MyEntity struct {
     PF []byte `json:"-" datastore:"_pf"`
  }
```

Querying without a Projection works fine. However, when I query with projection on "_pf" field, I get "type mismatch: string versus []uint8" error. I implemented the PropertyLoadSaver and examined the prop.Value for "_pf" property and found that some rows return []byte type and some return string. So, why is projected query failing with this error while non-projected queries are fine? At the moment I am resolving this by implementing PropertyLoadSaver interface and explicitly checking types and converting string type to []byte type to solve this problem.

Here is the complete test case. This is reproduced on cloud datastore emulator. Use appropriate value for datastoreProject variable below. Rest all should directly work. You can see the behavior by inserting both entities or one of the types of the entities. The error that is displayed is

```
panic: datastore: cannot load field "_pf" into a "tests.MyEntity": type mismatch: string versus []uint8 [recovered]
    panic: datastore: cannot load field "_pf" into a "tests.MyEntity": type mismatch: string versus []uint8
```

Following is the code.

```
type MyEntity struct {
    PF []byte `json:"-" datastore:"_pf"`
}

func TestPackedField(t *testing.T) {
    e1 := &MyEntity{PF: []byte{83, 0, 0, 0, 93, 150, 154, 206, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3}} // returns []byte on projection
    e2 := &MyEntity{PF: []byte{83, 0, 0, 0, 93, 120, 79, 87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3}}   // returns string on projection

    ctx := context.Background()

    conn, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, datastoreProject)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    bkey := datastore.NameKey("Bytes", "bytearray", nil)
    if true {
        conn.Put(ctx, bkey, e1)
    }
    skey := datastore.NameKey("Bytes", "string", nil)
    if true {
        conn.Put(ctx, skey, e2)
    }

    q1 := datastore.NewQuery("Bytes").Order("-_pf").Limit(2)
    var elfull []*MyEntity
    if _, err := conn.GetAll(ctx, q1, &elfull); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    q2 := datastore.NewQuery("Bytes").Project("_pf").Order("-_pf").Limit(2)
    var elprojected []*MyEntity
    if _, err := conn.GetAll(ctx, q2, &elprojected); err != nil {
        conn.Delete(ctx, bkey)
        conn.Delete(ctx, skey)
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you, please provide some code where are you doing the projection queries? Could you, also, give some data example? What is returned as []byte, what is returned as string?

Comment: Thank you Andrei. Updated the post with the test case and sample data.

Answer (score -1):

In order to understand why this works fine on normal queries and not on projection queries you might want firstly to read about what is the actual difference between those two. As it is mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780085/projection-queries-vs-regular-queries):

> Whereas "regular" (which I'm taking to mean SELECT * ...) queries against Cloud Datastore typically use indexes that only contain a sorted subset of the properties of the queried entities, plus pointers to the full entities, projection queries run against indexes that contain all the fields requested by the query. So it appears the significant latency gain comes from the elimination of the need to fetch the queried entities once the set of entities matching the query has been discerned via the index.

So, basically, when you do your projection query, your queried entities are not fetched.

As I was reading through this [official documentation](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Property), I found some really interesting phrases related to your question :

> A field of slice type corresponds to a Datastore array property, except for []byte, which corresponds to a Datastore blob. If a non-array value is loaded into a slice field, the result will be a slice with one element, containing the value.
>
> Key Field
>   If the struct contains a *datastore.Key field tagged with the name "**key**", its value will be ignored on Put. When reading the Entity back into the Go struct, the field will be populated with the *datastore.Key value used to query for the Entity.

What I understood from here is that maybe in your case, the fields are populated with the key value for that query ( string ).

Another interesting thing that I have discoverd is that according to the [properties and values type documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/entities#Properties_and_value_types) the type []byte is not indexed. And as it is told [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries#Limitations_on_projections), unindexed properties cannot be projected. So projected queries should not work for this particular use case at all.

Comment: "type []byte is not indexed" is not correct. https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore states strings and byte slices more than 1500 bytes can't be indexed. My data is well within that. As I mentioned, the projection is working and returning correct data, just the data type has mismatch. Changing string to []byte and then loading to the struct works correctly (correct data).

Comment: It is correct. Please read this official Datastore documentation. It is not a Go thing, it is a Datastore thing. --https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/entities#Properties_and_value_types . It that table it shows in the Note colomn for []byte - "Note indexed". Then, if you read further, there will be the phrase : "Because long byte slices and long strings are not indexed.....".

Comment: Anyhow, that is not so important. All I was suggesting is that, as projection query does not fetch with the actual entity value, in order for it to work, it may be automatically converted to string behind the scenes( as you have a string key , as I can see). So this is a possible reason for your type mismatch.

Comment: appengine go sdk had datastore.ByteString which is for byte arrays up to 1500 and that field can be indexed. In Cloud Datastore Client Library, there is no datastore.ByteArray. Instead, []byte type is used and based on the length it will be stored as either of those types. What I don't get is some rows are projected with correct type while others are not.

Comment: I agree with you about the datastore.ByteString. But you are using []byte which are not indexed ( it is stated very clearly on Google Cloud official documentation ). Projected queries can be used only on indexed properties ( very clearly stated in the Google Cloud official documentation,also). I understand your question clearly, and the reason why your result is that way, is because you are misusing the projected queries. You cannot use projected queries on []byte.

Comment: This response seems misleading. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/32c4871cc0f0b65184fbf116be8651e98305a7e9/datastore/save.go#L401 explicitly checks for []byte array size and only if it's more than 1500 and called without setting NoIndex, it throws an error.

Comment: Another documentation supporting that it is possible to project on byte arrays less than or equal to 1500, https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-datastore-array-value-inequality-range-go "Projection is not supported for strings that are longer than 1500 bytes, byte arrays that have more than 1500 elements, and other properties explicitly marked as unindexed."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200695/discussion-between-andrei-tigau-and-siva).